# Python not found using Systemctl

Tags: python, celerybeat, systemctl

Hy guys, I have an error in **systemctl** that tells me that the python was not found. In my .service file below, I run celery-beat. In my tasks.py, I have a code snippet that uses `os.system` to run python code.

```sh
# My .service
[Unit]
Description=Celery Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=ubuntu
Group=ubuntu
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/my_project_folder
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/home/ubuntu/enviq/bin/celery -A projectdjango worker -l info -B --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler &'
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s TERM $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

```sh
# Error when execute sudo journalctl -xe
Apr 30 16:13:01 ip-172-31-17-187 sh[16228]: [2020-04-30 13:13:01,155: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: app_iq_option01.tasks.get_candles_tasks[d1d14df
Apr 30 16:13:01 ip-172-31-17-187 sh[16228]: sh: 1: python: not found
Apr 30 16:13:01 ip-172-31-17-187 sh[16228]: sh: 1: python: not found
```

```py
# In this line I use the module os to call main_tasks.py
command = "python main_tasks.py {} {} {} '%s'".format(cred.email, cred.password, cred.max_samples)
command = command % coins
os.system(command)
```

When I run the command to run the celery through the terminal without using systemctl, it works normal. Anyone can help me with this? I really appreciate! It seems that systemd does not recognize my virtualenv (It calls venviq).

Comment: I don't know but do you need to use an absolute path to the python executable?

Comment: My executable is inside my project folder and I didn't need to, but I'll try it.

Comment: Thanks @jcfollower, but this is not the problem!

Comment: I was referring to the python programming language executable, like /usr/bin/python.

Comment: This is not the problem, I passed ```/usr/bin/python``` and also tried with ```/home/ubuntu/enviq/python``` and it didn't work. Thanks anyway!

Comment: It seems that systemd does not recognize my virtualenv